# What object type is the instance element parameter pass into the link function of an angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, typescript

I am using typescript with angular and trying to create a custom directive.  I am attempting to give all my parameters types, but am not sure what type the object that is pass through the $element parameter is.  Is it JQuery type?  Or some Element type?

In the directive code, I want to use $element with a d3 selector.  (i.e. d3.select($element))  Currently the d3 selection statement doesn't work because the $element type is not one that is expected by d3.  (I'm using a typescript interface for d3 as well.)

```
var directiveDefinitionObject : ng.IDirective = {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: { data: '=chartData' },
        link: ($scope: ICustomScope, $element: <WHAT_TYPE?>) => {
             d3.select($element);  // d3.select(node)
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$element` in the `link` function of a Directive has the type `ng.IAugmentedJQuery`. If you include jQuery then you will get the jQuery functions on `$element`, without jQuery then Angular will provide jqLite. [See here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) for more information.

The `link` function in `ng.IDirective` is defined as:

```js
link?: (scope: IScope,
        instanceElement: IAugmentedJQuery,
        instanceAttributes: IAttributes,
        controller: any,
        transclude: ITranscludeFunction
       ) => void;
```

Comment: Thanks!  In my version of angular.d.ts, the link definition actually is like this: 
link?:
            (scope: IScope,
            instanceElement: any,
            instanceAttributes: IAttributes,
            controller: any
            ) => void;
Which is why I couldn't figure out the type.  So using IAugmentedJQuery, I was able to get "d3.select($element[0])" to run properly.  What type is $element[0]?  Is there a way to tell from the definition of IAugmentedJQuery?

Comment: I should clarify my question.  The definition I have for IAugmentedQuery is interface IAugmentedJQuery extends JQuery {
        // TODO: events, how to define?
        //$destroy

        find(selector: string): IAugmentedJQuery;
        find(element: any): IAugmentedJQuery;
        find(obj: JQuery): IAugmentedJQuery;

        controller(name: string): any;
        injector(): any;
        scope(): IScope;

        inheritedData(key: string, value: any): JQuery;
        inheritedData(obj: { [key: string]: any; }): JQuery;
        inheritedData(key?: string): any;


    }

Comment: How do you know you can use [0] on it?  How do you know that's an array by looking at this definition?  I'm new to typescript and just so I don't have to ask this sort of question in the future, I'd like to know how I can figure out these types by myself.  Same with the SVGSVGElement type that you said is expected by d3.select.  How did you know this?  The d3 documentation only said it expects a "node".
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_select

Comment: You can use `[0]` safely because that's how jQuery works. It will always provide that index as a reference to the underlying HTML object. You are right `d3` is just expecting a node. As such just passing `d3.select($element[0])` should be fine, and correctly typed.